# Testing Modbus Connection with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, modbus, pymodbus

I am trying to test the modbus portion of a python project I am currently implementing. I have two modbus devices that I am reading using [pymodbus](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [ascyio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

The goal of this test is to see the deviation in read time when more threads are added that read a given modbus device. Each thread will only read one modbus device but given I only have two devices some threads will share devices. The thread scripts look something like this shown below:

```
# IP address of the smart meter 
meter_IP = "192.168.0.80"

async def main(meter):
    file_name = "results/thread_two_result.csv"
    with open(file_name, mode='a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        print("Executing thread two event loop")
        while True:
            await meter.read_all(csv_writer)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop, client = ModbusClient(schedulers.ASYNC_IO,host =meter_IP, loop=loop)
meter = smart_meter(meter_IP,client)
loop.create_task(main(meter))
loop.run_forever()
```

The class for implementing the modbus read portion is contained in the class `smart_meter` and the only function I am using is the `read_all` function, which takes an input of a csv file which a time stamp is written to when the result from modbus is obtained. Each thread has its own csv file. I am reading 12 registers with this function in a single modbus query. This is shown in the code snippet below:

```
class smart_meter():

    ## __init__ ##
    # Initialiase method to intatiated object 
    # Inputs:
    #   IP - The IP address of the smart meter 
    #   client - A modbus client of type 'pymodbus.client.asynchronous.asyncio.ReconnectingAsyncioModbusTcpClient'
    def __init__(self,IP,client):
        #Create the client object passing the IP address of the slave to it 
        logger.info(f"New instance of smart_meter instantaited with IP of {IP}")
        self.IP = IP
        #self.client - 'pymodbus.client.asynchronous.asyncio.ModbusClientProtocol' 
        self.client = client.protocol

    ## read_all ##
    # Reads the registers:
    # V_2 - 0x1112
    # I_2 - 0x1114
    # kW_2 - 0x1116
    # kvar_2 - 0x1118
    # kVA_2 - 0x111A
    # PF_2  - 0x111C 
    async def read_all(self,file):
        logger.info(f"Attempting to read all registers for channel two")
        try:
            response = await self.client.read_input_registers(0x1112,12) 
            reg_value = dict.fromkeys(["Volts","Current","kW","kvar","kVA","PF"])
            x,y = 0,2
            for key in reg_value:
                reg_value[key] = (BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(response.registers[x:y],Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Little )).decode_32bit_float()
                x+=2
                y+=2
            file.writerow([datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]])
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception("Error in reading all regeisters for channel two")
```

The run script for running these threads is a shell script which looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

python thread_one.py &
python thread_two.py &
python thread_three.py &
python thread_four.py &
python thread_five.py &
python thread_six.py &
python thread_seven.py &
python thread_eight.py &
```

I have got up to eight threads running currently with threads 1,2,3 and 7 reading from meter_1 and threads 2,4,6 and 8 reading from meter_2. The test which only implemented 7 threads ran well however the 8 thread test is beginning to fail. The response from the modbus read is starting to return a `None` value, the traceback from one of the threads captured in the log file is shown below:

```
2020-04-18 16:08:32,599:ERROR:4446:MainProcess:smart_meters.py:Error in reading all regeisters for channel two
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/openhabian/Environments/env_1/openHAB_Proj/openHAB_Proj/smart_meters.py", line 77, in read_all
    response = await self.client.read_input_registers(0x1112,12)
  File "/home/openhabian/Environments/env_1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymodbus/client/common.py", line 125, in read_input_registers
    return self.execute(request)
  File "/home/openhabian/Environments/env_1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymodbus/client/asynchronous/asyncio/__init__.py", line 129, in execute
    self.write_transport(packet)
  File "/home/openhabian/Environments/env_1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymodbus/client/asynchronous/asyncio/__init__.py", line 119, in write_transport
    return self.transport.write(packet)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

This is resulting in no results being obtained for some threads as it is already queuing up the next read for that thread which again results in a `None` type being returned. I am running these tests on a [RasberryPi 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/).

Is it that I am just reaching the limits of the hardware/software? If anyone has an suggestions about how to implement a better test they would be welcome.

**EDIT**

The thread files are pretty much all the same only difference is the modbus device they are reading from and the csv file that I am saving values too stored in the variable `file_name`. The even threads (2,4,6,8) all read from the same modbus device, an even thread file is shown below for `thread_eight.py`

```
# IP address of the smart meter 
meter_IP = "192.168.0.80"

async def main(meter):
    file_name = "results/thread_eight_result.csv"
    with open(file_name, mode='a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        print("Executing thread eight event loop")
        while True:
            await meter.read_all(csv_writer)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop, client = ModbusClient(schedulers.ASYNC_IO,host =meter_IP, loop=loop)
meter = smart_meter(meter_IP,client)
loop.create_task(main(meter))
loop.run_forever()
```

The odd thread file(1,3,5,7) all read from the same device. An example of an odd file is shown in the code below from the file `thread_seven.py`

```
# IP address of the smart meter 
meter_IP = "192.168.0.116"

async def main(meter):
    file_name = "results/thread_seven_result.csv"
    with open(file_name, mode='a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        print("Executing thread seven event loop")
        while True:
            await meter.read_all(csv_writer)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop, client = ModbusClient(schedulers.ASYNC_IO,host =meter_IP, loop=loop)
meter = smart_meter(meter_IP,client)
loop.create_task(main(meter))
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your `thread_eight.py`?

Comment: I put it in the edit of the question as I did not have enough space for a comment